# VB.NET WPF Ribbon 2010 .net 4.0 does not work 3.5 does

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, .net-4.0, ribbon

I just installed Microsoft Ribbon for WPF 2010 on 2 different windows 7 boxes. If I make a .net 3.5 project it works fine but a .net 4.0 it does not.

I can load the sample ribbon application and it works but when I drag the ribbon controls over they just make a transparent box.

I notice it does not make the XAML correct. Here is the code, 4.0 on top then 3.5 below it. Is there some setting or option I need to change?

```
<ribbon:Ribbon Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="618" />
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,36,0,0" Name="RibbonGroup1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    <ribbon:RibbonTab Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,50,0,0" Name="RibbonTab1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,80,0,0" Name="RibbonGroup2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />


<my:Ribbon Height="139" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503">
        <my:RibbonTab Header="Tab" Name="RibbonTab1">
            <my:RibbonGroup Header="Group" Name="RibbonGroup1">
                <my:RibbonButton Label="Button" Name="RibbonButton1" />
            </my:RibbonGroup>
        </my:RibbonTab>
    </my:Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Ribbon control (Oct 2010 release) is a joke. They got it working..."mostly" and then left it full of bugs without fixing them. "It will work properly in the next version of Visual Studio"...um, okay.

I tried to use it and was constantly frustrated. DevComponents has a pretty solid Ribbon control for WPF. I recommend it. But I still have a couple of issues with that one, too.

Good luck!

Comment: I have seen DotNetBar and do like it, however I am a basic programer and either make stuff for fun at home or simple in group programs at work. So the Microsoft versions being free is nice. I end up pretty much just coding the XAML myself and just making sure it looks how I want in the design view. Guess I might have to wait for .net 4.5...